# Vue 3 Production build doesn't have correct assets, but dev build does

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a Vue 3 app to Firebase Hosting. I have previously successfully deployed Vue 2 apps to Firebase Hosting using a very similar file structure and setup.

The problem is that when I'm deploying to Firebase all my images and assets aren't shown in the web page. When inspecting the individual elements in the inspector I can see the images and they are actually uploaded to Firebase Hosting, but it doesn't show on the actual website. The same happens when trying to run 'npm run serveProd'.

When running 'npm run serve' in development mode all my images and assets work perfectly.

I'm using Typescript, Vue 3 and Babel. Here's my firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  }
}
```

Here's my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `
              @import "@/styles/variables.scss";
              @import "@/styles/text.scss";
              @import "@/styles/elements.scss";
          `,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The assets are placed in the **public directory**. I've not changed above files much, so I thought default behaviour should work but it doesn't.
I've tried everything and would highly appreciate some guidance or pointer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit - based on our discussion in the comments

###### general configurations (specifically vuejs config)

The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at your `publicPath`.
This is the equivalent of webpack's `output.publicPath`, but Vue CLI also needs this value for other purposes.

By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. https://www.my-app.com/. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at [https://www.foobar.com/dist/](https://www.foobar.com/my-app/), set publicPath to `'/dist/'`.

The value can also be set to an empty string ('') or a relative path (./) so that all assets are linked using relative paths. This allows the built bundle to be deployed under any public path, or used in a file system based environment like a Cordova hybrid app.

This value is also respected during development. If you want your dev server to be served at root instead, you can use a conditional value:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```

###### regarding index.html

The file `dist/index.html` is a template that will be processed with [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.my-app.com/). During build, asset links will be injected automatically. In addition, Vue CLI also automatically injects resource hints (preload/prefetch), manifest/icon links (when PWA plugin is used), and the asset links for the JavaScript and CSS files produced during the build.

Since the index file is used as a template, you can use the lodash template syntax to interpolate values in it:

- `<%= VALUE %>` for unescaped interpolation;
- `<%- VALUE %>` for HTML-escaped interpolation;
- `<% expression %>` for JavaScript control flows.

In addition to the [default values exposed by `html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates), all [client-side env](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code) variables are also available directly. For example, to use the BASE_URL value:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

---

in your `firebase.json` you should change `"public": "dist"` to `"public": "/"`,

basically what happens is that your URLs are looking for a subfolder named `/dist/`, but the public folder is indeed dist, so you just need to take that out of the image tags.

For example, replace
*https://*some_url*.com/dist/tasker_logo.png* with *https://*some_url*.com/tasker_logo.png* and you'll see the image you're looking for.

if that's not working Try to give the full path instead of `../assets/logo.png` try `src/assets/logo.png` or something like that. it should be a **complete** path

Comment: Here's a screenshot of how it looks like in the inspector. https://i.imgur.com/YWEp6nP.png